# Objective-C: How to get data from selected row in table?

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I need to retrieve a string from **data from a selected row in a table** to compare it to a string.

I call

```
NSArray *values = [self.tableArrayController selectedObjects];
```

To get the objects at the selected row. However, values only has a count of objects of 1, and everything seems to be one big, long string of all my values. I cannot search through the values because I won't always know what to search for. I need a specific value (of which they are organized by columns).

I was hoping that the array would be of a certain count and I could retrieve the string based on the index of the object for the string.

How should I get all the different values (organized by columns) for a selected row?

EDIT:

I populate a NSDictionary (withmore values than that, this is just an example). The string value is the column identifier. The object is the object I'm adding that I want to appear on the table. This part below already works as I want it to:

```
NSDictionary *dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         object1, @"column",                      
                         object2, @"column2",
                         nil];
[self.tableArrayController addObject:dict];
```

Comment: what kind of objects is your array controller serving up, and in what format are those objects (e.g. NSDictionary objects or?)??

Comment: Show us how you populate NSArray with data.  To quickly explain, if you want to handle multiple fields, you may want to use an NSMutableArray with NSMutableDictionary to populate data that the tableview control in question points to unless you want to put comma-separated different fields or something into each object with NSArray.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, they're strings loaded into a NSDictionary as seen in the edit.

Comment: @TBlue check my updated question (under "EDIT:").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to get data from your table is to look at the "`NSTableView`" methods "`selectedRow`" & "`selectedColumn`".

With that information, you can get at the value you want directly via your array controller or you can use the NSTableViewDataSource method "`tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`" to pass you back the NSString value of whatever it is that you're trying to get at.

Comment: Thanks. This is probably what I'll end up doing.